# Angular HttpClient Errorhandler best way

Tags: angular

What's the best way to handler error
in HttpClient.

Can this be a good way?

My goal is to avoid set the same
method over and over again in all service.

```
export class HttpErrorHandler {
  static handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      errorMessage =  error.error.message;
    } else {
      const errorMessage = `Server returned code: ${error.status}, error message is: ${error.error}`;
    }
    const msg = environment.production ? 'Something bad happened; please try again later.' : errorMessage;
    return throwError(msg);
  }
}
```

or by an ErrorHandler like

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorsHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  handleError(error: Error | HttpErrorResponse) {   
   if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      // Server or connection error happened
      if (!navigator.onLine) {
        // Handle offline error
      } else {
        // Handle Http Error (error.status === 403, 404...)
      }
   } else {
     // Handle Client Error (Angular Error, ReferenceError...)     
   }
  // Log the error anyway
  console.error('It happens: ', error);
}
```

Comment: these questions are better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this...This is best way to handle error as per your requirement.Just need to create only one method in service class like below.

```
 public errorHandler(err: HttpErrorResponse) : Observable<any>
  {
    if (err.error instanceof Error)
    {
      console.error("Client-side error occured.",err.status,err.error.message);
      console.error(JSON.stringify(err.error));
    }
    else 
    {
      console.error("Server-side error occured.",err.status,err.error.message);
      console.error(JSON.stringify(err.error));   
    }

    return ErrorObservable.throw(err || 'ERROR');
  }
```

and while accessing from component class just subscribe method to handle error in better way like below

```
     .subscribe(
        res => {
               console.log(res) ;
               },
        err => { 
                //**here you do action whatever you want like this** if(err.status==409){}else{}
               }
            );
```

.In this you don't have to create errorHandler for every rest call..you just need to subscribe it and do action on particular HttpError